# accents not showing with htmlspecialchars() and using mysqli

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a MySQL database with words in spanish with accents such like andreá for example.

i was using this and it is showing fine:

```
<?php
include "../BD/conexion.php";
mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8');

class Faq
{

public $pregunta;
public $respuesta;


public function __construct($pregunta,$respuesta)
{
    $this->pregunta    = $pregunta;
    $this->respuesta  = $respuesta;

}

public static function get()
{
    $rows = array();
    $res  = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM Faq');

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
        $rows[] = $row;
    }
    function filter(&$value) {
      $value = htmlspecialchars($value,  ENT_QUOTES | ENT_SUBSTITUTE, 'UTF-8');
    }
    array_walk_recursive($rows, "filter");
    return $rows;
}
```

When i print rows in the html it shows fine like so:

[image]

But i was trying to change to the new mysqli_ functions like this:

```
<?php
$conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","prueba2");
mysqli_query($conexion,'SET NAMES utf8');
mysqli_close($conexion);

class Faq
{

public $pregunta;
public $respuesta;


public function __construct($pregunta,$respuesta)
{
    $this->pregunta    = $pregunta;
    $this->respuesta  = $respuesta;

}

public static function get()
{
    $conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","prueba2");
    $rows = array();
    $res  = mysqli_query($conexion,'SELECT * FROM Faq');

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
        $rows[] = $row;
    }
    function filter(&$value) {
          $value = htmlspecialchars($value,  ENT_QUOTES | ENT_SUBSTITUTE, 'UTF-8');
    }

    array_walk_recursive($rows, "filter");
    return $rows;
    mysqli_close($conexion);
    return $rows;

}
```

and when i show it i get:

[image]

i tried to use 
     mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf8")

but it has the same output... help =(

Comment: Have you tried running both scripts on the same page to make sure that the problem comes from mysqli_ and not something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe if you run a query to set the names before you do any other queries, it should work. Somewhat of a shot in the dark though!

As seen here: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php#44707

```
<?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","","prueba2");
    $mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    $q = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM Faq");
?>
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified. I think you need to do it within each connection you open. You did set it, but then closed that connection, and opened a new one.

Comment: Thank you now it works, if i dump the array after doing htmlspecialchars() i get holÃ¡ andreÃ¡ is that ok? is there anyway to do it and not having to call set names every time? @Scott Rowell

Comment: I'm not exactly sure! (Again, it was a shot in the dark!) It was the only thing I noticed that was different between your two pieces of code. It kind of sucks to do two queries every time. What you COULD do is not close the original connection. Then set the SQL connection timeout to something reasonable on your server (something like 30 seconds).

Answer (score 0):

Check the charset in your table. If it's not utf-8, then it wouldn't make a difference because it would have converted the charset to how it understands it before spitting it out.

[Use this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8906813/how-to-change-the-default-charset-of-a-mysql-table) as additional information

Comment: Thanks, yes they are in utf8