# How to convert an entire MySQL database when text was Not correctly stored, and stored in some other charset

Tags: mysql

[image: in this image you can see this problem]

SOURCE CODE  OF SQL FILE IS:

```
    -- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.0.4.1
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1
-- Generation Time: Oct 20, 2021 at 07:03 PM
-- Server version: 5.5.32
-- PHP Version: 5.4.16

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `test`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `test_table`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test_table` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` text CHARACTER SET utf8
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

--
-- Dumping data for table `test_table`
--

INSERT INTO `test_table` (`id`, `title`) VALUES
(2, 'ÛŒØ§Ø´ÛŒÙ„ Ù‚Ø·Ø±Ù‡'),
(3, 'ØªÙˆØ³Ø¹Ù‡ ØµÙ†Ø¹Øª ÙØ±Ø¢ÛŒÙ†Ø¯ Ø¨Ø§Ø®ØªØ±'),
(4, 'Ø§Ù„ÙˆÙ†Ø¯ Ù…Ú©Ø´'),
(5, 'Ù†Ù‡Ø§Ø¯Ù‡ Ú¯Ø³ØªØ±'),
(6, 'Ù¾Ø§Ú©Ø§Ù† Ø¨Ø°Ø±');

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

link to :

![sample query for this problem][2]

**What is the problem: **

By using of

> ALTER DATABASE

and

> ALTER TABLE

commands.
same as

```
ALTER DATABASE databasename CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

ALTER TABLE tablename CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

we can convert an entire MySQL database characterset and collation to UTF-8
**when text was Not correctly stored**
but my problem is that: ALTER TABLE tablename CHARACTER SET utf8
only sets the default charset on a table which is used for newly created columns.
And it does not convert existing columns that already have a char set.
how do it only by MySQL Commands and without exporting to file

pay attention:
**This problem started when the character settings (character set ) in the server settings were not set correctly to utf8 and remained unchanged on latin1, which is mysql by default setting.**

Edit: add source sql insted linking to it

Comment: Look using CLI, not via web-client.

Comment: for this problom i can not search a word in it

Comment: please include a sample sql  exported from your db. I want  to import it in  my local db and work on it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the default charset of a MySQL table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8906813/how-to-change-the-default-charset-of-a-mysql-table) There are answers there that show how to use a procedure to do so, so you can change it a little bit to cover all tables.

Comment: i check it (by replace of table name and column) but  There is nothing happening

Comment: @(saeed arab sheybani ) you can get sample file from this link: https://bayanbox.ir/download/9207589261626850516/test-table.zip

Comment: @saeedarabsheybani Please do not add irrelevant tags.

Comment: Please [edit] this question to type or paste in the code rather than linking to a zip file containing it. As it stands now, your zip file makes it hard to answer your question or for people with related issues to find your question. See the [formatting documentation](/editing-help) for tips to make your code appear nicely inline.

Comment: The magic is inside `CONVERT TO` - it not only changes the column definition but also converts the content of the column from the old to the new charset.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller
added SQL source insted linking to it

Comment: The data you are inserting appears to be corrupt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Well-Defined problems lead to breakthrough solutions

Check out this  simple solution:

```
UPDATE `test_table` SET `title` = CONVERT(CAST(CONVERT(title USING latin1) AS 
BINARY)  USING utf8)
```

Left: Run code

Right: Result of code

[image]
Thanks,
[IVO GELOV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5962802/ivo-gelov)

He is right

**The magic was inside CONVERT TO**